# Apply free shipping promotion when reordering from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, promotions

I've made a promotion rule under `Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules`. It enables free shipping for shopping cart less than 2 KG.

Conditions:
Total Weight equals or less than 2.

Actions:
Free shipping -> For shipment with matching items

I enabled **Flat Rate** shipping method with price of 10$ as well.

Customers can see the free shipping option in checkout page, and admin user can create a new order with free shipping from admin panel. But when admin user tries to reorder, **Flat Rate** price is 10$ and the promotion did not apply. See screenshot below:

[image]

Is it possible to apply the promotion in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, It's been like this.

The problem seems to be related to Quote creation, i.e. after you click on `reorder` button in Admin panel, cart promotions can not be applied immediately. instead you need to click on `Update Items and Qty` on top of the newly created order page and then click on `Click to Change Shipping Method` in Shipping method section.

Comment: Is their any way it can be refresh without click on Update Items and Qty ?